Как исправить и доработать алгоритм для работы с массивами
Я решал задачу на массивы: Вводится массив целых чисел. Найти наиболее длинную подпоследовательность подряд идущих элементов такую, что все элементы данной подпоследовательности равные за исключением 2-х произвольных элементов (реализовать функцию, которая будет возвращать позицию первого элемента такой подпоследовательности и кол-во элементов). В случае нескольких таких подпоследовательностей найти самую первую. Например, для массива {4, 5, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 6, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1} правильным ответом будет { 5, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3 } (также существует еще три таких подпоследовательности длиной 6 – {3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7},{4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7} и {6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1}).
Разработал алгоритм, он работает, но не совсем правильно, так как цикл, перемещающий нижний индекс работает не правильно, как его пофиксить?
сам код
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static int[] InputArray(){
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements of the array: ");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    int[] numbers = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter element %s: ", i+1);

        int e = scan.nextInt();

        numbers[i] = e;
    }

    return numbers;
}
public static void OutputArray(int[] array){

}

public static int[] solution(int[] array){
    int n = array.length;
    if (n < 3) {
        return null; // Невозможно найти такую подпоследовательность
    }

    int r = 1;
    int l = 0;

    int m = 0;

    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;

    int counter = 0; //переменная считающая сколько следующих элементов равны первому 
    элементу

    while (r < n) {

        if (array[r] == array[l]){ 
            counter++;
        }

        while (r - l - counter + 1 > 3) { // сам проблемный цикл
            l++;
            if (array[r] == array[l]){
                counter--;
            }
        }

        if (counter >= 2){ 
            if ((r - l - counter + 1 == 3) && (r - l > maxIndex - minIndex)) {
                maxIndex = r;
                minIndex = l;
            }
        }

        r++;
    }

    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, minIndex, maxIndex + 1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = InputArray();

    int[] array2 = solution(array);

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array2));
}

}

зачем вообще с первым элементом сравнивать? Эта логика даже на ваших примерах не сработает ведь, когда первый элемент - это один из двух произвольных { 5, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3 }

Опишите алгоритм в вопросе.

Любой подмассив длинной <= 3 подходит под критерии. Вы зачем-то отбрасываете подмассивы длинной 0, 1, 2.

Вашу задачу можно решить как минимум двумя способами.
Решение предпросмотром
Например, простым предпросмотром вперёд. Для текущего положения i смотрим вперёд - насколько длинным будет искомый подмассив, если он начнётся в позиции i. Таким образом будут построены все подмассивы, из них выбран наибольший.
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * Класс Solver1 предоставляет методы для поиска подмассивов с ограниченным
 * числом уникальных элементов.</br>
 * 
 * Используется алгоритм "грубой силы", который пробегает по всем значениям
 * индексов и предпросматривает подмассивы вперёд, как если бы лучший подмассив
 * начинался с текущего индекса.</br>
 * 
 * Константы:
 * <ul>
 * <li>DEFAULT_UNIQUE_COUNT - значение по умолчанию для uniqueCount.
 * </ul>
 * Методы:
 * <ul>
 * <li>matchingEnd(int start): Возвращает индекс конца подмассива, в котором
 * содержится не более uniqueCount уникальных элементов.
 * <li>bestRange(): Находит и возвращает лучший диапазон в массиве, где число
 * уникальных элементов не превышает uniqueCount.
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param arr         массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
 * @param uniqueCount максимальное количество уникальных элементов в подмассиве.
 * 
 */
public class Solver1 {
    /**
     * Массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
     */
    private final Integer[] arr;
    /**
     * Максимальное количество уникальных элементов в подмассиве.
     */
    private final int uniqueCount;
    /**
     * Значение по умолчанию для uniqueCount.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_UNIQUE_COUNT = 3;

    /**
     * Конструктор для создания объекта Solver1.
     *
     * @param arr         массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
     * @param uniqueCount максимальное количество уникальных элементов в подмассиве.
     */
    public Solver1(Integer[] arr, int uniqueCount) {
        if (uniqueCount < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unique count should be greater than 0");
        }
        this.arr = arr;
        this.uniqueCount = uniqueCount;
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор для создания объекта Solver1 с uniqueCount по умолчанию.
     *
     * @param arr массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
     */
    public Solver1(Integer[] arr) {
        this(arr, DEFAULT_UNIQUE_COUNT);
    }

    /**
     * Находит и возвращает лучший диапазон в массиве.</br>
     * Лучший диапазон определяется как самый длинный подмассив,
     * в котором число уникальных элементов не превышает uniqueCount.
     *
     * @return объект Range, представляющий лучший диапазон в массиве.
     */
    public Range bestRange() {
        Range best = new Range(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - best.len(); i = skipSameVal(i)) {
            var end = matchingEnd(i);
            if (end - i > best.len()) {
                best = new Range(i, end);
            }
        }
        return best;
    }

    
    /**
     * Возвращает индекс конца подмассива, в котором содержится не более uniqueCount
     * уникальных элементов.
     * Подмассив начинается с индекса start.
     *
     * @param start начальный индекс для поиска.
     * @return индекс первого элемента после конца искомого подмассива.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException если start находится вне массива.
     */
    public int matchingEnd(int start) {
        if (start < 0 || start >= arr.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        var numbers = new HashSet<Integer>(); // Множество уникальных элементов подмассива.
        numbers.add(start);
        for (var i = skipSameVal(start) ; i < arr.length; skipSameVal(start)) {
            var v = arr[i];
            if (numbers.contains(v)) {
                // Этот элемент уже есть в подмассиве
                continue;
            }
            if (numbers.size() == uniqueCount) {
                // Подмассив должен содержать не более uniqueCount уникальных элементов.
                // Добавление текущего элемента приведёт к превышению лимита.
                return i;
            }
            // Добавляем текущий элемент в множество уникальных элементов.
            numbers.add(v);
        }
        return arr.length;
    }

    /**
     * Пропускает элементы массива с одинаковыми значениями, начиная с указанного индекса.
     * 
     * @param start начальный индекс для проверки.
     * @return индекс первого элемента, который отличается от элемента на позиции start,
     *         или длину массива, если все последующие элементы одинаковы.
     */
    private int skipSameVal(int start) {
        var v = arr[start];
        for (int i = start + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != v) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return arr.length;
    }
}

Сложность решения порядка n^2, где n - размер массива.
Решение без предпросмотров
В этом решении тянется список из уже просмотренных диапазонов одинаковых чисел.   В списке поддерживается инвариант - число уникальных элементов из диапазонов, хранящихся в списке, не превышает заданное (в вашем случае 3). Если добавляется диапазон с четвёртым уникальным элементом, диапазоны из головы списка отбрасываются, чтобы выполнить инвариант.
/**
 * Класс Solver2 предоставляет методы для поиска подмассивов с ограниченным
 * числом уникальных элементов.</br>
 * 
 * Для поиска подмассива максимальной длины алгоритм делает один проход.
 * Хранится список диапазонов одинаковых значений.</br>
 * 
 * Константы:
 * <ul>
 * <li>DEFAULT_UNIQUE_COUNT - значение по умолчанию для uniqueCount.
 * </ul>
 * Методы:
 * <ul>
 * <li>bestRange(): Находит и возвращает лучший диапазон в массиве, где число
 * уникальных элементов не превышает uniqueCount.
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param arr         массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
 * @param uniqueCount максимальное количество уникальных элементов в подмассиве.
 * 
 */
public class Solver2 {
    /**
     * Массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
     */
    private final Integer[] arr;
    /**
     * Максимальное количество уникальных элементов в подмассиве.
     */
    private final int uniqueCount;
    /**
     * Значение по умолчанию для uniqueCount.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_UNIQUE_COUNT = 3;

    /**
     * Конструктор для создания объекта Solver2.
     *
     * @param arr         массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
     * @param uniqueCount максимальное количество уникальных элементов в подмассиве.
     */
    public Solver2(Integer[] arr, int uniqueCount) {
        if (uniqueCount < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unique count should be greater than 0");
        }
        this.arr = arr;
        this.uniqueCount = uniqueCount;
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор для создания объекта Solver2 с uniqueCount по умолчанию.
     *
     * @param arr массив целых чисел, в котором выполняется поиск.
     */
    public Solver2(Integer[] arr) {
        this(arr, DEFAULT_UNIQUE_COUNT);
    }

    /**
     * Находит и возвращает лучший диапазон в массиве.</br>
     * Лучший диапазон определяется как самый длинный подмассив,
     * в котором число уникальных элементов не превышает uniqueCount.
     *
     * @return объект Range, представляющий лучший диапазон в массиве.
     */
    public Range bestRange() {
        if (arr.length == 0) {
            return new Range(0, 0);
        }

        NRangeList ranges = new NRangeList(uniqueCount);
        Range maxRange = new Range(0, 0);

        for (int i = skipSameVal(0); i < arr.length; i = skipSameVal(i)) {
            var prev = arr[i-1];

            ranges.add(prev, i);
            if (ranges.len() > maxRange.len()) {
                maxRange = new Range(ranges.start(), ranges.end());
            }
        }
        ranges.add(arr[arr.length-1], arr.length);
        if (ranges.len() > maxRange.len()) {
            maxRange = new Range(ranges.start(), ranges.end());
        }
        return maxRange;
    }

    /**
     * Пропускает элементы массива с одинаковыми значениями, начиная с указанного
     * индекса.
     * 
     * @param start начальный индекс для проверки.
     * @return индекс первого элемента, который отличается от элемента на позиции
     *         start,
     *         или длину массива, если все последующие элементы одинаковы.
     */
    private int skipSameVal(int start) {
        var v = arr[start];
        for (int i = start + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != v) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return arr.length;
    }
}

Поддержание инварианта в списке диапазонов возложено на класс NRangeList:
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Класс NRangeList представляет собой список диапазонов одинаковых чисел,
 * идущих подряд в массиве.
 * 
 * Он позволяет добавлять новые диапазоны, проверять, пуст ли список, обрезать
 * список до максимального количества уникальных значений,
 * а также получать начальную и конечную позиции диапазонов и их суммарную
 * длину.
 *
 * Пример использования:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * NRangeList nRangeList = new NRangeList(3);
 * nRangeList.add(1, 5); // число 1 повторяется 5 раз
 * nRangeList.add(2, 10); // число 2 повторяется 5 раз
 * nRangeList.add(3, 15); // число 3 повторяется 5 раз
 * nRangeList.add(4, 20); // Список будет обрезан до 3 уникальных значений
 * </pre>
 */
public class NRangeList {

    /**
     * Список объектов диапазонов значений.
     */
    private List<NRange> nRanges;
    /**
     * Множество уникальных значений N.
     */
    private Set<Integer> cache = new HashSet<Integer>();
    
    /**
     * Максимальное количество уникальных элементов.
     * 
     * Если при добавлении очередного диапазона количество уникальных значений превысит это значение,
     * список диапазонов будет обрезан до максимального количества уникальных значений.
     */
    public final int MAX_UNIQUE_COUNT;

    /**
     * Конструктор для создания списка диапазонов.
     *
     * @param uniqueCount максимальное количество уникальных значений N
     */
    public NRangeList(int uniqueCount) {
        if (uniqueCount < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unique count should be greater than 0");
        }
        MAX_UNIQUE_COUNT = uniqueCount;
        nRanges = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, пуст ли список диапазонов.
     *
     * @return true, если список пуст, иначе false
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return nRanges.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Обрезает список диапазонов до максимального количества уникальных значений N.
     *
     * @return true, если список был обрезан, иначе false
     */
    public boolean truncate() {
        if (cache.size() <= MAX_UNIQUE_COUNT) {
            return false;
        }
        var set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = nRanges.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var r = nRanges.get(i);
            if (set.contains(r.N)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (set.size() < MAX_UNIQUE_COUNT) {
                set.add(r.N);
                continue;
            }
            nRanges.subList(0, i + 1).clear();
            cache = set;
            return true;
        }
        throw new AssertionError("Should not reach here");
    }

    /**
     * Добавляет новый диапазон в список. Диапазон начинается с последнего диапазона
     * в списке.
     * 
     * Если при добавлении нового диапазона дисло уникальных значений N превышает
     * максимальное количество,
     * список диапазонов обрезается до максимального количества уникальных значений
     * N.
     *
     * @param N   число, которое повторяется в диапазоне
     * @param end конечная позиция диапазона
     * @return    true, если список был обрезан после добавления, иначе false
     */
    public boolean add(Integer N, int end) {
        if (end <= this.end()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range end is not greater than the last range end");
        }
        cache.add(N);
        nRanges.add(new NRange(N, end(), end));
        return truncate();
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает начальную позицию первого диапазона в списке.
     *
     * @return начальная позиция первого диапазона, или 0, если список пуст
     */
    public int start() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return nRanges.getFirst().range.start;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает конечную позицию последнего диапазона в списке.
     *
     * @return конечная позиция последнего диапазона, или 0, если список пуст
     */
    public int end() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return nRanges.getLast().range.end;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает суммарную длину диапазонов из списка.
     *
     * @return длина диапазона
     */
    public int len() {
        return end() - start();
    }

    /**
     * Внутренний класс NRange представляет диапазон одинаковых чисел, идущих подряд
     * в массиве.
     */
    private static class NRange {
        /**
         * Число, которое повторяется в диапазоне.
         */
        public final Integer N;
        /**
         * Диапазон индексов массива.
         */
        public final Range range;

        /**
         * Конструктор для создания диапазона NRange.
         *
         * @param n     уникальный идентификатор диапазона
         * @param start начальная позиция диапазона
         * @param end   конечная позиция диапазона
         */
        public NRange(Integer n, int start, int end) {
            N = n;
            range = new Range(start, end);
        }

        /**
         * Возвращает строковое представление объекта NRange.
         *
         * @return строковое представление объекта NRange
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "NRange{" + "N=" + N + ", range=" + range + '}';
        }
    }
}

Полное решение здесь: https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/tree/main/java/1602165
